# Android ConstraintLayout generates absolute values

Tags: android, android-layout

I have recently started learning the new `ConstraintLayout` in Android Studio 2.2 and noticed that when I add simplest of the views, the layout editor automatically generates some absolute coordinates. Here is a sample XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_portfolio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abc.Activity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/creator_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="246dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="479dp"
        android:id="@+id/first_textview"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Notice the absolutes like `81dp`, `246dp`, `479dp`... I tried to manually delete these, but when I go back to the "Design" tab and come back to the "Text" tab, these regenerate. Now, I have three questions:

1. Is there a way to tell Android Studio to not generate these?
2. Should I manually place them in `dimens.xml`?
3. Would these absolutes cause some layout problems in other devices?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You'll note that all of the absolute values are in the `tools` namespace - this means they are not compiled into your app, nor used in anything but in the tools (and in this case, the visual editor). They are simply to ensure that switching from the Design to Text tab is always consistent, with the underlying files remaining stable.

> 1. Is there a way to tell Android Studio to not generate these?

No.

> 2. Should I manually place them in dimens.xml?

These are only useful for the tools and therefore should not be added to a separate `dimens.xml` file that would be included in your final APK.

> 3. Would these absolutes cause some layout problems in other devices?

No, they are only used by the tools.

Comment: But I did add constraints. I have pasted only a part of the layout, but the other parts also got the same hardcoded values... So, should I just ignore these hardcoded values? Could I do anything about them?

Comment: I took another look at your XML and reworked my answer - the `tools` namespace is for the tools/Editor only and don't make any difference in your final app's behavior.

Comment: thats really valuable tip Ian

Comment: Well in my case the IDE keeps changing a layouts layout_width from a dimen value to a specific DP. Its very annoying.

Comment: They are really frustrating. Need way to disable them

Comment: absolute value mess up my layout. Also it removes my margins

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure your original question contains your entire layout, as it references a widget with an id of `@+id/activity`, so the issue might lie elsewhere in your layout.

Ensure that no widget that exists within a `ConstraintLayout` has a `layout_width` or `layout_height` of `match_parent`.

> MATCH_PARENT is not supported for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout, though similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

If you use `match_parent`, Android Studio will generate these absolute values, as well as replacing `match_parent` with an absolute dimension.

Based on the layout you posted, your `TextView` probably had a `layout_width` or `layout_height` of `match_parent` before Android Studio replaced it.

You should replace `android:layout_width="match_parent"` with

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndtOf="parent"
```

And `android:layout_height="match_parent"` with

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomtOf="parent"
```

In your specific layout, you probably want something like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_portfolio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abc.Activity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/creator_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first_textview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side notes to given answers, you can use the **Magic Wand Icon** in the toolbar menu above the design preview. Click on **Infer Constraints** button, this will automatically add some lines in the text field and the tools one  will be converted to constrained.

Please see below picture :

[image]