# Make child view group fill the rest of the parent group downwards

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Consider the case of when one wants a View within a LinearLayout to fill out the rest of the empty space in the layout; one then sets the weight of this view to 1, while the weights of the others are 0.

Is there any way at all to do a similar thing with a child view group within a parent view group.

For example, consider my xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/coffee"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:alpha="0.7"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/bus_title"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="About Us"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/about_heading"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/bus_description"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opening_hours_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/about_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours_header"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opening_times"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/opening_hours_header"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Contact_Us_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/opening_times"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Contact_heading"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/Contact_Us_heading">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#80E0E0E0"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Type a message here..."
                android:layout_below="@id/Contact_Us_heading"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="SEND" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

You'll see that below several textViews I insert a child LinearLayout.

I want the Linear Layout to fill the 'remaining space' downwards of the RelativeLayout, in the same way that the editText View fills the rest of the LinearLayout.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with a `RelativeLayout` but you can convert it into a `ConstraintLayout` and use `app:constraintVerticalWeight="1"` to control the height of the main EditText component.

In fact, you can do away with the nested `LinearLayout` entirely as `ConstraintLayout` can do it all for you in one go!

The modified layout XML would look something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/coffee" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/bus_title"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/about_heading"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="About Us"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/about_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/bus_description"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/opening_hours_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_heading" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opening_hours_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours_header"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/opening_times"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opening_times"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/opening_hours"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Contact_Us_heading"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/opening_hours_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Contact_Us_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Contact_heading"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/email_field"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/opening_times" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#80E0E0E0"
            android:hint="Type a message here..."
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/send_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Contact_Us_heading"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEND"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_field" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The resulting layout looks like this in the AndroidStudio UI designer (ignoring the missing string/drawable definitions, and noting I changed the text colour to black so that we could see the location of the text views):

[image: Example layout]

Comment: Hey I noticed you added some attributes like this: 'tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-16dp"'

Could you explain in beginner's terms what this attribute does? I'm struggling to find a concise answer.

Comment: No, I did not add those attributes. I have not edited the code snippet in my answer and cannot see any reference to the tools namespace or those attributes..  I presume Android Studio must have added them automatically when you converted your layout. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505641/android-constraintlayout-generates-absolute-values) for information on what they do.